# Electric Field Due to uniformly charged infinitely long wire

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, indeterminate-forms

**Calculate the field at a point P at distance r from infinitely long wire with charge density $\lambda$**
Generally the electric field in this case at point P, distance r from the wire is derived using  [image: Gauss Law]:
[image: Diagram of the required]

$$ \vec E . 2 \pi r l = \frac{\lambda l}{\epsilon _○}$$
**I tried to do the same but using Coulombs law**

As force between two point charges is given by:(field is force per unit charge)
$$\vec F = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_○}×\frac{Q_1 Q_2}{r^2}(\hat r)= \frac{kQ_1Q_2}{r^2}(\hat r)$$
And Vertical components get cancelled out

I defined the following integral:

$$\int^\infty _{-\infty} \frac{k}{r^2+x^2}\cos \theta \ dQ$$$$=\int^\infty _{-\infty} \frac{k}{r^2+x^2}×\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+x^2}} \ \lambda \ dx$$

It finally evaluates to $$\frac{k \lambda}{r} × \left[\frac {x}{\sqrt{x^2+r^2}}\right]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$$

1. *Is my process correct?*
2. *How do I further evaluate to obtain the expression by putting the limits?*
3. **I proceeded without knowing what to do and got** $$\frac{k\lambda}{r}×\left[ \frac{\infty}{\infty}- \frac{- \infty}{\infty} \right]$$$$ = \frac{k \lambda}{r}× \frac{2×\infty}{\infty}=\frac{2k\lambda}{r}$$

The doubt is:  Since in this case the answer comes out correct. **Does it it mean we can treat indeterminate forms by cancelling infinity with infinity as equal to 1/1 like in this case?** I know it is wrong mathematically but does it generally give the correct answer treated this way?*(in similar cases maybe)*

Comment: Obviously you cannot cancel infinities like that. But **in this very special case, you were fortunate**, and the answer is correct. The limit as $x\to\infty$ is indeed $1$, and the limit as $x\to -\infty$ is $-1$. So the difference is $2$, which is the factor you got. To see these are the limits, factor out $x^2$ from the square root in the denominator, then cancel with the $x$ in the numerator (be careful with signs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When evaluating integrals 'at infinity' you cannot just plug $\infty$ into the equations at the end.

You were definitely on the right path though, to make the end a bit more formal you can use limits: (the limits will be evaluated informally though)
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}(r) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{1}{r^2+x^2} \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+x^2}} \lambda\: \mathrm{d}x\\
&= \frac{\lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r} \left[ \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+r^2} }\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}\\
&= \frac{\lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r} \left( \lim_{x\to \infty} \left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+r^2} } \right]- \lim_{x\to -\infty} \left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+r^2} }\right] \right) \\
&= \frac{\lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r} \left( \lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{{x^2+r^2} }}+ \lim_{x\to -\infty} \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{{x^2+r^2} }} \right) \\
\end{align}
where i've used that the second limit has an $x$ in the numerator so for $x \to -\infty$ we have $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+r^2}} = - \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2+r^2}}$

by dividing both de numerator and the denominator by $x^2$, we'll get
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}(r) = \frac{\lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r} \left( \lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{{1+\frac{r^2}{x^2}} }}+ \lim_{x\to -\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{{1+\frac{r^2}{x^2}} }} \right) \\
\end{align}
and $\frac{r^2}{x^2}$ tends to $0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ so:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}(r) = \frac{\lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0r} \left(1 + 1 \right)
\end{align}
so we do indeed get the same answer as we'd gotten earlier with Gauss' law!

There are various sources to learn integrals with 'infinities' such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) or [this one](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ImproperIntegrals.aspx)